# After changing passwords, git now returns error. How might I resolve this error?

Tags: git

Today, my company password expired forcing me to reset it.  I use sourcetree for Windows, and Windows 7.  After changing my password, and my sourcetree authentication settings I am starting to receive strange git errors when I try to checkout a branch.  I can log and diff files, but I can't checkout a branch.  Below is the error:

```
$ git checkout develop
warning: unable to access 'u://.config/git/ignore': Permission denied
fatal: cannot use u://.config/git/ignore as an exclude file
```

I've seen threads that have said something about the HOME variable being wrong, but I didn't change that.  Things were working fine earlier in the day before the password change.  Now I have no clue what is going on.  In this case home is set to a network drive not root so I don't think that the threads talking about the root directory offer the correct solution for me.

Here is some more context.  Within sourcetree if I try to open a submodule or checkout a branch I get this error.

> 'git status' failed with code 128: warning: unable to access
>   'u:/.config/git/ignore': Permission denied

Curiously, I have no hidden .config directory at all in my home directory.  Perhaps something got deleted?  Am I supposed to have one?  I'm also confused about the '/' characters within the message.  It's all fairly cryptic to me.

If I run git config --list from a git bash prompt I get the following at the end of the output

```
mergetool.sourcetree.cmd='C:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 3/BComp.exe' "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$BASE" "$MERGED"
mergetool.sourcetree.trustexitcode=true core.editor=vim

**fatal: error processing config file(s)**
```

It isn't clear what git doesn't like about the config file or if it is looking for something else, but I've looked at the .gitconfig file and I see no obvious problems.

Comment: You may not have access to that U:// drive anymore.

Comment: I can access the directory just fine using windows explorer.

Comment: git config --list --global doesn't fail with the fatal error so the global config file appears to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Update the Sourcetree password for the given repository:

```
Tools | options | Authentication
```

[image]

Comment: I already did that.  It seems to have no effect.  Thanks for the suggestion though.  I have also tried logging out, logging back in, and rebooting the PC to no avail.

Comment: Check you .gitconfig file to see if you have any settings there. There might be.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but sourcetree is responsive for some things.  For instance, I can diff, log, blame, and things like that.  Sourcetree doesn't seem to have an access problem so it isn't complaining with errors about connecting to stash.

Comment: only remote commands like push pull fetch require connection so will ask for password. all other commands are local.

Comment: And as you can see from your update  your config file has some bad line i it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by uninstalling GIT and Sourcetree, and then reinstalled both.  it isn't clear whether this was more of an IT issue or if some config file became corrupted so this might not help a lot of people.  The git error was quite ambiguous and the references to the U drive had to do with how our IT department sets up network share for our windows user directory so that it exists on the network rather than on my hard disk.  After it is fixed, I can run the git config --list command to see that it is showing all of the information.  When it wasn't working it was only able to show the things within the global config file.  The config information associated with each repo that I have setup including current branch checkouts was not able to be read.  I just don't know why uninstalling and resinstalling sourcetree fixed that.